# I want to keep websocket connection run forever but i get this "ConnectionClosedOK: received 1000 (OK); then sent 1000 (OK)"

Tags: python, websocket

I want to stream data from tradingview and add it into a panda df for every symbol, not familiar with websockets/async but after some copy paste from here i got stuck, the problem is that after ~1 minute 20 seconds the connection is closed (want the code to keep running forever/till it gets manually closed)

The 'error' is "ConnectionClosedOK: received 1000 (OK); then sent 1000 (OK)".

```
import json 
import websockets
#import websocket
import pandas as pd
import urllib
import asyncio
import time
import string
import random
import re
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from websockets import client
from websocket import create_connection
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()


wsParams = {"from": "symbols/BINANCE-ETHUSDT/"}
websocketUri = f"wss://data.tradingview.com/socket.io/websocket?{urllib.parse.urlencode(wsParams)}"

def generateChartSession():
    stringLength=12
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    random_string= ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))
    return "cs_" +random_string
    
initMessages = [
    {"m": "set_data_quality", "p": ["low"]},
    {"m": "set_auth_token", "p": ["unauthorized_user_token"]}]

symbols = ['BINANCE:LRCUSDT', 'BINANCE:ADAUSDT', 'BINANCE:ETHUSDT', 'BINANCE:IMXUSDT', 'BINANCE:BTCUSDT']
dfs={} #store tick data received in df 
symbols_session_link = {}

i=0
for symbol in symbols:
    i+=1
    session =  generateChartSession()

    initMessages.append({"m":"chart_create_session","p":[session ,""]})
    initMessages.append({"m":"switch_timezone","p":[session ,"Etc/UTC"]})

    lastPart = '={\"symbol\":\"' + symbol+  '\",\"adjustment\":\"splits\",\"session\":\"extended\"}'
    initMessages.append({"m":"resolve_symbol","p":[session ,f"symbol_{i}",lastPart]})
    initMessages.append({"m":"create_series","p":[session ,"s1","s1",f"symbol_{i}","1",2]},) #last 2x 1 min bars for symbol 

    symbolName = symbol.split(":")[1]
    symbols_session_link[session] = symbolName
    df = pd.read_csv('G:\\My Drive\\Python Daytrading\\stock data\\test\\' + symbolName + '.csv ')
    dfs[symbolName] = df #big dfs that contains all symbols df 


def strip(text):
    noDataReg = re.match('~m~\d+~m~~h~\d+', text, re.MULTILINE)
    if not noDataReg:
        dataReg = re.split('~m~\d+~m~', text)
        return [json.loads(t) for t in dataReg if t]
    return []

def unstrip(text):
    return f"~m~{len(text)-8}~m~{json.dumps(text)}"

async def init(websocket):
    for m in initMessages:
        await websocket.send(unstrip(m))


async def startReceiving(websocket):

    data = await websocket.recv()
    await init(websocket)

    while(True):

        data = await websocket.recv()
        payloads = strip(data)
        for p in payloads:
            #read from p date + OHLC + volume
            try:
                last_tick = [[t["v"][0], t["v"][1], t["v"][2],t["v"][3], t["v"][4], t["v"][5]] #date open low high close volume
                for t in p["p"][1]["s1"]["s"]]
            
                #transform data received for minute and subtract 1 to be as it should on tradingview
                candleMinuteTime = p["p"][1]["s1"]["lbs"]['bar_close_time']
                candleMinuteTime = datetime.fromtimestamp(candleMinuteTime)
                candleMinuteTime = candleMinuteTime.replace(minute= candleMinuteTime.minute-1)
                candleMinuteTime = candleMinuteTime.__str__()
                
                #add tick/last 1 minute bar to df
                if dfs[symbols_session_link[p['p'][0]]].tail(1).datetime.values[0] != candleMinuteTime:
                    row = {'datetime': candleMinuteTime, 'symbol': symbols_session_link[p['p'][0]], 'open': last_tick[0][1], 
                            'high': last_tick[0][2], 'low':last_tick[0][3], 'close': last_tick[0][4], 'volume':last_tick[0][5]}
                    dfs[symbols_session_link[p['p'][0]]] = dfs[symbols_session_link[p['p'][0]]].append(row, ignore_index = True)
                    time.sleep(0.05)
                else:
                    dfs[symbols_session_link[p['p'][0]]].at[dfs[symbols_session_link[p['p'][0]]].index[-1], 'open'] = last_tick[0][1]
                    dfs[symbols_session_link[p['p'][0]]].at[dfs[symbols_session_link[p['p'][0]]].index[-1], 'high'] = last_tick[0][2]
                    dfs[symbols_session_link[p['p'][0]]].at[dfs[symbols_session_link[p['p'][0]]].index[-1], 'low'] = last_tick[0][3]
                    dfs[symbols_session_link[p['p'][0]]].at[dfs[symbols_session_link[p['p'][0]]].index[-1], 'close'] = last_tick[0][4]
                    dfs[symbols_session_link[p['p'][0]]].at[dfs[symbols_session_link[p['p'][0]]].index[-1], 'volume'] = last_tick[0][5]
                    time.sleep(0.05)

                print(symbols_session_link[p['p'][0]], candleMinuteTime, last_tick[0][4])
                print()
                print()

                    
            except:
                # print('fail')
                pass


async def websocketConnect():
    async with websockets.client.connect(websocketUri, extra_headers= {
            "Origin": "https://www.tradingview.com"
        }) as websocket:
        print(f'started websocket')
        await startReceiving(websocket)

# asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(websocketConnect())
# .run_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(websocketConnect())
    # my_loop.close()`
```

I think my problem is with websocketConnect() ('async with' closes the connection?) and probably need to send a ping?
Tried a lot of things (websocket/s library, ping, without async with) from here but I just can't seem to use them properly

Comment: Have you checked if the server uses a timeout?

Comment: I don't know how to do that but found this [link](https://github.com/mohamadkhalaj/tradingView-API/blob/main/tradingView.py) and change it a bit with the part from the code above and it's working.
I think the problem was the connection was closed in websocketConnect() and not sending pings to the server so i guess the server timed out?
Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: Probably, most (any well-managed) production servers have timeouts for inactivity. Those connections cost money and they don't want to pay for indefinitely idle connections.